# Doing the impossible - Embedding an mongoDB document that has not yet been created..?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm creating a data base of user accounts with embedded profile documents so I can store the data separately but in a way where they are still linked. I want to include a the ID of the user account within the profile document in order to reference the user account in my app without passing the user account info to the client (eg email and password).

The problem is that for the user ID to be generated the user document needs to be created, but if I create the user document first then I cant link the profile to it as it has not yet been created. If I try to tackle this from the other way round then I cant add the userID to the profile as the ID will not yet have been created...

```
    const newProfile = new Profile ({
      companyName: companyName,
      eventGenre: eventGenre,
      area: area,
      established: established,
      description: pDescription,
      userID: //(this should be the ID of the user docuemnt created below)
     })

     newProfile.save()      

     
     const newUser = new User ({
       email: email,
       password: password,
       remeberMe: 0,
       accountType: 1,
       promoterProfile: newProfile,
       venueProfile: null
     })

     newUser.save(function(err){
       if(err){
         console.log(err);
       }
```

Comment: Could you allow the link to be undefined with the idea that you'll make it right later?  Something like "save the profile without a user id.  Save the user.  update the profile with the just created user id".  You could wrap that whole thing in a function like `createProfileWithUser` or something.  Certainly there's a case where it might fail.  I don't know if mongo has the notion of a transaction but if it did you could make sure if any step failed it'd unroll all of them.  If not, you might just have to include guards for the odd cases where that 3 step process failed.

Comment: I managed to solve it by generating an ID with the uuid library earlier. This way I could plug the ID into both fields upon creation. Thanks for the comment though! hopefully this will help some poor bugger out in the future who needs to stick with the original IDs hahah!